# Ошибка 500 при переносе сайта. на зеркале все работает без проблем

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на **wordpress**, которому необходим перенос на другой хостинг c домена на латинице на домен на кириллице. 
На 2ом хостинге создан и привязан домен с кириллическим доменным именем и создана соответствующая папка (на латинице). Перенес сайт, бд, [настроил переконвертацию доменного имени с помощью сервиса](https://mothereff.in/punycode). Как итог: в админку пускает, стандартную тему отображает, а вот в созданной вызывает 500 ошибку - в логах:

> [24-Nov-2016 07:37:39] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/name/wp-content/themes/themes-name/front-page.php on line 116
>   [24-Nov-2016 07:38:57] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/name/wp-content/themes/themes-name/front-page.php on line 116

в этом месте - 116 строка `<?php $section_gates = new WP_Query([`:

```
<?php $section_gates = new WP_Query([
                        'post_type'     => 'section_gates',
            'name'     => 'sektsionnye-vorota',
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                        'order'         => 'ASC'
                    ]); 
                while($section_gates->have_posts()): 
                     $section_gates->the_post();
```

На латинском зеркале все работает без проблем и ошибок при этом.
В чем причина, как найти и устранить ошибку?

Comment: @Geyan читайте внимательно `.htaccess удалил`

Comment: эта ошибка из за того что кэш браузера забит хламом , я же попросил ссылку на сайт и если обнаружится что у меня работает а у вас нет ...

Comment: @Geyan кеш браузера тут не причем - в разных точках города, на разных устройствах все одинаково. кое-что удалось исправить - изменил в описании к чему пришел

Comment: речь о wordpress ?

Comment: Версия PHP какая? В php.ini short_open_tag включены?

Comment: в общем эта проблема не новая : читайте https://otvet.mail.ru/question/167086725 и заметьте что ответ выбран как лучший

Comment: @Ninazu а при чём  short_open_tag ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На латинском зеркале у вас версия PHP 5.4+ а на "проблемном" версия ниже. Проблема возникает из-за того, что только начниная с версии 5.4 стали поддерживаться литералы массивов. То есть теперь можно писать так:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

На более ранних версиях нужно писать так:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Решить проблему можно так (в порядке сложности):

1. Сменить версию PHP (многие хостеры это позволяют);
2. Сменить хостера;
3. Поменять все упоминания литеральной записи массива на `array(...)`.

Comment: Советую попробовать пункт №1, потом пункт №2, а 3 никогда не использовать :)

Comment: @ilyaplot Разные бывают ситуации

Comment: Платить хостеру деньги за продукт, который устарел несколько лет назад и не иметь возможность обновить движок? Плохая ситуация.

Comment: @ilyaplot Ситуации бывают и плохими :)